# If a site includes the header 'HTTP Content-Security-Policy require-sri-for' then does this include all nested scripts?

Tags: integrity, content-security-policy

If I'm using subresource integrity on a web page and a script that I import then itself imports a further script, will the CSP 'require-sri-for' also include those subsequent, nested, imported scripts?

For example, if a .js file is pulled in by the main web page and it includes reference to a further .js file, the top level file's hash won't change if the URL of the further .js file doesn't change but the code at that URL has. So the top level file will pass its SRI check even though that script is then pulling in an unchecked script.

Or does CSP 'require-sri-for' checking get inherited by the scripts that are then loaded and so own down the import chain (if there is one)?

Comment: On a side note, I would recommend against the quite experimental `require-sri-for` and instead opt for the better supported `strict-dynamic`, which is designed to propagate trust.

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not mean that. This header tells the browser to enforce SRI check on every single script you have on the page.

If you use:

```
Content-Security-Policy: require-sri-for script
```

You must add the integrity attribute of every script you use:

```
<script src="https://some.code.com/example1.js"
    integrity="sha256-5i/mQ...yXWA="></script>

<script src="https://some.code.com/example2.js"></script>
```

So if you don't use `integrity` attribute on any script, it won't load. So `example2.js` above will not be loaded.

Comment: I understand that (although thanks for your answer). What I'm asking about is what if a script is loaded that has the integrity attribute, but *that* script pulls in another script. Is that latter script included in the check for the integrity attribute e.g. 'example1.js' pulls in another script 'example3.js'?

Comment: I don't think you can include a script on another script. You can use AJAX to retrieve a script and manipulate the DOM to include it, but this does not change the first script, so SRI only applies to the first, not to anything you load later.

Comment: Here is an interesting snippet which (I assume) is dynamically creating a script tag in the DOM? i = function(e, t) {
                e.find("script").remove();
                var n = document.createElement("script");
                n.src = "https://<some URL>", n.type = "text/javascript", n.setAttribute("async", ""), n.setAttribute("defer", ""), e.append(n)
            },